# How to store results of a simulation and plot all the results in one plot using plot_KDE in Luminescence package for R

Tags: r, plot, simulation

I am creating a simulation using random number simulations. This gives 100 sets of 45 values with error.

First I would like to store the results of these simulations.
I then need to plot the results of these simulations on one plot. The plot I need to produce uses the package Luminescence and is of the type KDE.
I have managed to produce the separate entities but am struggling to both store the results and to produce the plot with all the simulations.
So far I have created the simulation:

```
Simulation <- function() {
    RNC <- rescale (SFMT(45, dim=1, mexp=216091, 
                            usepset=T, withtorus= F, usetime=T), 
                    c(0.01,130))
    RNC_error <- RNC*0.15
    df <-data.frame(RNC,RNC_error)
}
```

the plot I want to create uses the following:

```
library("Luminescence")
plot_KDE(data=df, na.rm = TRUE,
         values.cumulative = TRUE, order = TRUE, 
         boxplot = F, rug = F,
         summary.method = "MCM", bw = "nrd0", 
         output = TRUE)
```

For my final result I require the numerical results of all the simulations stored and a single KDE plot with the results of all the simulations.

Comment: When asking a question, try and make it as easy as possible. For example, you don't need the `Simulation` function. You just need a data frame `df`, i.e. `df = data.frame(x = 1:5, y=runif(5))`

Answer (score 0):

Split your problem into two parts.

1. Storing results. You have  a data frame, `df`, so just use `write.csv()` to store the results to a CSV file, i.e.

   ```
   write.csv(df, file="some_file.csv")
   ```
2. Storing your plot. Obviously you can't use a csv file, so instead we'll use a `pdf` or `png`, e.g.

   ```
   # Open the file
   pdf("figure_file.pdf")
   plot_KDE(data=df, na.rm = TRUE,
       values.cumulative = TRUE, order = TRUE, 
       boxplot = F, rug = F,
       summary.method = "MCM", bw = "nrd0", 
       output = TRUE)
   # Close the file
   dev.off()
   ```

   To save as a `png` use `png()` instead of `pdf()`

Comment: My issue isn't storing the results of the individual parts but rather, I need to store the results of the 100 iterations of the dataframe of 45 values each with their error value and the plot on a single plot the KDE results of these 100 iterations.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What does 100 iterations of the dataframe of 45 values each mean. What is an iteration of a dataframe.

Comment: Apologies, I'm using iteration in a none mathematical sense here.

Comment: Apologies, I'm using iteration in a none mathematical sense here.
To clarify: I am running through the code that produces the dataframe 'df' 100 times.  Each time I run the code to produce df I get a dataframe of two columns of 45 values, the first column being the values, the second being the error.The results I wish to store and subsequently plot on a single KDE plot are the outputs of these 100 runs of the code.

Comment: OK. So why not dynamically create a file name, e.g. `pdf(paste0("graph", i, ".pdf))` where `i` is the current iteration between 1 and 100